# Limitação de parâmetro dinâmico no Crystal Reports

Tags: parâmetros, crystal-reports

Criei um relatório no Crystal Reports que vai exibir os dados de um Projeto gerado no sistema SCIA.

O usuário deve selecionar o Projeto a ser emitido no relatório em uma lista de valores do parâmetro Projeto criado como dinâmico no Crystal Reports 2011 - versão 14.0.4.738.

Esta lista de seleção está em ordem decrescente para facilitar a localização dos últimos Projetos gerados no SCIA.

Problemas:

1. A lista de valores do parâmetro Projeto está limitada, isto é, só apresenta um número limitado de Projeto onde deveria apresentar todos gerados no SCIA. Como eliminar essa limitação?
2. O uso de parâmetro dinâmico impede que o usuário digite um outro Projeto que não está exibido na lista. Como liberar para o usuário digitar no parâmetro um dado que está fora da lista para seleção?
3. Como criar um outro parâmetro aninhado a esse parâmetro anterior, por exemplo Fases do Projeto?

Se alguém sabe como resolver, agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Bom dia amigo, acredito que você irá precisar acrescentar mais detalhes na pergunta, pois ao menos eu, não consegui entender o que você já tem e o que deseja fazer.